# Closing holes in mesh while retaining point cloud shape

Tags: python, mesh, point-clouds, surface, open3d

I have a ply file that I am attempting to turn into a mesh for the purposes of ray tracing. It looks like this is the open3d visualizer and is supposed to represent a part of a city:
[image]

I used open3d to get make the following mesh as following(kdtree is just to get small number of points as file is huge):

```
input_file = "san.ply"
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(input_file)
point_cloud_in_numpy = np.asarray(pcd.points)
color = np.asarray(pcd.colors)
kd = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(point_cloud_in_numpy) #create kdtree for fast querying
near = kd.query_ball_point([0, 0, 0], 100)
items = point_cloud_in_numpy[near]
colors = color[near]
pcd2 = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()

pcd2.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors)
pcd2.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(items)

pcd2.estimate_normals()

distances = pcd2.compute_nearest_neighbor_distance()
avg_dist = np.mean(distances)
radius = 2 * avg_dist

mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_ball_pivoting(
       pcd2,
       o3d.utility.DoubleVector([radius, radius * 2]))

vertices = np.asarray(mesh.vertices)
faces = np.asarray(mesh.triangles)

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh])
```

However, when graphing the mesh, we get something that looks like this:
[image]
Many holes and just not at all optimal for ray tracing. I also tried using the `create_from_point_cloud_poisson` method instead however I kept on getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] /Users/yixing/repo/Open3D/build/poisson/src/ext_poisson/PoissonRecon/Src/FEMTree.IsoSurface.specialized.inl (Line 1463)
        operator()
        Failed to close loop [6: 87 64 18] | (113981): (2752,2560,2196)
```

which I found no way to fix online. I tried looking around but the best I found was pymeshfix which doesn't even work because "The input is assumed to represent a single closed solid object", which my point cloud is obviously not. I'm just looking for a good way to perform surface reconstruction that lets me keep the shape of the city while also fixing all the holes and making all surfaces created by points near eachother surfaces watertight.

Comment: Pick a larger radius?

Comment: Doesn't work properly. I multiplied the avg distance by 20 for the radius and it took over half an over to create the mesh AND it still had many holes.

Comment: Facing similar issue and looking for a method to close gaps

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can close the holes with fill_holes() from the tensor-based TriangleMesh:

```
mesh = o3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh.from_legacy(mesh).fill_holes().to_legacy()
```

fill_holes() takes a parameter for max. hole sizes to be closed

http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh.html#open3d.t.geometry.TriangleMesh.fill_holes

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/pyvista/pymeshfix

```
vclean, fclean = pymeshfix.clean_from_arrays(vertices, faces)
```